# How i can identify Simulink blocks containing named constants Matlab R2013b

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to search for Simulink blocks containing named constants in my model. Is there  any block parameter to know if it has a named constant or not ?

Comment: Are you searching for block parameters that are editable but has a variable name? Can you give an example of what you are looking for?